# Как реализовать функцию "времени осталось" ?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Ответ где то на поверхности плавает, не знаю как правильно реализовать)) 
У нас есть:

```
а = 100
b = x
```

a всегда равно 100м, а вот b динамическая. 
На странице есть

```
<div class="percent" style="width: 0%;">Идет конвертация</div>
```

В width передается текущее значение b.

Вопрос - как мне сделать таймер примерного подсчета сколько времени до конца осталось?

То-есть я примерно понимаю, что при запуске функции на обновление `b` нужно вызвать ещё одну функцию, которая засечёт время до обновления самой переменной `b` и соотвественно когда `b` будет равна 1 - мы сможем посчитать сколько ещё секунд осталось до конца. 
К примеру время между тем как переменная `b` была равно 0 и 1 равно 3м секундам, соответственно время пока переменная `b` станет равна 100м будет 300 секунд, но что если следующее изменение переменной `b` (когда она станет равна 3м) меньше 3х секунд, да и как вообще оформить такой скрипт?)))

Comment: 0 -> 1 = 3с => 0 - 100 = 300с, 0 -> 3 = 6c => 0 - 100 = 200c, и т.д. т.е. показывать время, исходя из текущей средней скорости: a * (текущее время - время старта) / b. А оформить можно по разному. Последний раз делал прогресс с помощью websocket-а

Comment: А как это сделать в js ? )))

Comment: При запуске процесса `startTime = Date.now()`. Каждый раз при обновлении `b` `currentTime = Date.now()`. И получаем расчётное время в секундах так `estimatedTime = a * ((currentTime - startTime) * 1000) / b`

Comment: Ну спс, только считать по другому чуть-чуть нужно это самое оставшееся время.

Answer (score 0):

При запуске функции

```
startTime = Date.now();
var c = $('#progress').attr("current");
```

После изменения значения b

```
if(b != c) {
   currentTime = Date.now();
   estimatedTime = (a - b) * (currentTime - startTime);
   var c = $('#progress').attr( "current");
   startTime = Date.now();
}
```

Comment: Вам конечно видней. Но выскажу своё сомнение. Если a и b это допустим проценты (`%`), то в итоге у Вас получается `%` * `мс`, в то время как время (каламбур:) может быть только `мс` (ну и пр. ед. изм. времени). Надо уничтожить размерность `%`. Т.е. надо поделить на что-то, что является `%`

Comment: Ну я получаю целое число, а проценты добавляю уже в конце. 
Однако нужно сказать, что считает не верно всё равно, а точней верно считает только если действие не большого размера.

Comment: Вспоминайте физику. Имеется пройденное расстояние b. пройдено он за время (currentTime - startTime). Средняя скорость v = b / (currentTime - startTime). Надо пройти расстояние a - b). Сколько уйдёт на это времени при заданной скорости v? v = (a - b) / t => t = (a - b) / v = (a - b) / (b / (currentTime - startTime)) = (a - b) * (currentTime - startTime) / b. `t = (a - b) * (currentTime - startTime) / b`